# Connecting with Documentum using java project

Tags: documentum

Hi I'm new to Documentum, I want to connect to Documentum dql with my java code to perform select queries to fetch some data. How can I connect with the Documentum server in a java project and what are the requirements for the same?

Comment: Documentum docs are only for the customers. Those are javadoc html and PDFs. Some PDFs leaked online though. There's no trial version of Documentum. On the server you can find the required client jars including dfc.jar and some dependencies. There's also an official client package containing DFC and some extras

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the Documentum / OpenText DQL reference guide.

Comment: Hi Henning, can please provide any reference guide link on this, that can be referred. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @ShantanuSingh - just do a Google search for "opentext documentum dql reference" that should get you some hits. You are looking for a PDF document. Also the DFC reference guide would come handy when programming stuff on this platform. Happy coding :-)